# R ggplot2 dotplot difficulties

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I have a data, which is this:

```
Metai   World   Lithuania   Latvia  Estonia
1995    19.99274674 3.664078576 5.165501237 6.19899916
1996    20.1618143  3.584610154 5.203743587 8.848114633
1997    21.34178618 3.792669688 6.25751733  9.131262925
1998    22.0383053  3.290601838 3.978832389 11.69820107
1999    23.07794571 3.296374656 4.060777075 13.49890414
2000    24.46391466 4.458263805 3.959122402 29.9304493
2001    22.97296394 4.990611202 3.772830006 19.28104368
2002    22.24335355 3.770408263 3.867904265 11.86431239
2003    21.15902664 4.790428512 4.58911383  12.65710496
2004    20.93194705 4.721934472 4.885990508 13.99565801
2005    20.64893325 6.153892776 5.314174985 14.66002177
2006    20.79146459 8.057471159 6.821101055 12.62826088
2007    17.5236718  10.84503636 6.947695298 5.801621676
2008    16.71189963 11.14479194 6.953299326 5.401508192
2009    18.15846464 9.994402174 7.758518211 5.679785009
2010    17.58191783 10.60837644 7.644312054 9.265320112
2011    16.52156487 10.21171712 8.242904557 13.38765176
2012    16.97066134 10.42150357 9.777651216 10.75136222
2013    17.04950642 10.33111769 13.01214609 10.50099872
```

I started using R for my classes and want to to a dotplot which would look like this: [preffered dotplot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AUw9w.png). So I started on tutorial and so far my code looks like this. Please disregard weird naming - plots are for presentation in my language, and other plot, which I am ok with.

```
#nuskaitymas
ld4 <- read.csv(file="LD4.csv",head=TRUE,sep=",")
ld4

library(ggplot2)
library(tidyr)

laboras <- gather(ld4, 
                  value="Procentai",
                  key="Salis",
                  World, Lithuania, Latvia, Estonia)

plotas1 <- ggplot(laboras, aes(x=Metai,y=Procentai, color=Salis)) + geom_line()
plotas1 + scale_y_continuous(breaks=seq(0,30,1)) + scale_x_continuous(breaks=seq(1995,2013,1))

plotas2 <- ggplot(laboras, aes(x="Salis", y="Procentai")) +
  theme(legend.position="top", axis.text=element_text(size = 6))
(plotas21 <- plotas2 + geom_point(aes(color = Metai),
                                 alpha = 0.5,
                                 size = 6,
                                 position = position_jitter(width = 1, height = 0.25)))
```

The bad thing is - whenever I plot, not only I get weird one, not looking good at all - dots change positions everytime, even if my data was not changed. Looks like this: [bad plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UgMY5.png)

What am I doing wrong? Could you correct my code? Thanks

Comment: At a guess I think you need to change your data to long format. You can achieve this using `reshape2`. See here: http://seananderson.ca/2013/10/19/reshape.html

Comment: I did it so by using gather()

Comment: The `width` of your jitter looks much too large.  Try reducing it to something like .05.  To use the actual variables in your dataset in the last graph instead of constant remove the quotes around the variable names inside `aes`.